# Overriding Foursquare callback uri in an app

Tags: php, foursquare

I want to override the callback uri in our Foursquare app. I tried setting it manually using the method `setRedirectUri` and passing the url that should be used.

```
$uri = FF_WEBROOT_BASE_URL . '/me/networks/foursquare/redirect-uri';
$foursquareClient->setRedirectUri($uri);
```

When I test it there's an error in the Foursquare page saying:

```
Cause of error: Callback uri is not valid for this consumer
```

Is it possible to override the callback uri of that was set in the foursquare app's details just like Tumblr's and Twitter's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because the URL you're pointing your users to (foursquare.com/oauth2/...) includes a `redirect_uri` parameter that doesn't match with what you configured in your app's settings under https://foursquare.com/developers/apps. Make sure these match!